# Take GAE Endpoints generated via Android Studio to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a project that needs Android, iOS and desktop modules to connect to a GAE backend.

I created the backend through Android Studio and it works fine.

As I understand, Android Studio generates the endpoints class files and places them in some zip files (one for each Endpoint class) in the `project-folder/backend/build/client-libs`. Is this right?

I tried to create a desktop application using Eclipse (Mars), since I can't find any way to do it in Android Studio (can you confirm this is not possible?). I installed the AppEngine SDK plugin as instructed in [Google Cloud Eclipse Docs](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) and created a new Maven-based Google App Engine Standard Java project (Hello World template).

To connect the newly created project to the endpoints, I tried to configure the build path to include the zip files I found in the `client-libs` folder, but I can't find the files belonging to the model of the backend.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

"I'm still waiting for an answer on how to use the endpoints for both mobile and desktop clients." -> Have a look at these tutorials, and in particular parts 4 to 7.

https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-2-9ddba6799765#.2kijxun2b

Comment: Thank you!
This is the closest thing to what I'm looking for!
In the meantime, I started studying this example [vogella site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html#todo_jsp) and, more important, this [link on the google documentation] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating-guestbook), where I found some advices on how to connect through JSPs.

Comment: Happy that I could help you. Maybe you could accept the answer, even if it does not cover completely your very "wide" question :-)

Answer (score 0):

At present, the only way I found to have a desktop application talk to a Google App Engine backend is via servlets.
So I have to create a second way to connect to the backend. It's not as easy as I thought, but it works.
I'm still waiting for an answer on how to use the endpoints for both mobile and desktop clients.